# Access value of foreign-key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm working on my own Web-app but I'm facing a problem.
Here is my models :

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
      has_many :player_seasons
      has_many :forecasts, through: :player_seasons
    end

class PlayerSeason < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :season
  belongs_to :championship
  has_many :forecasts
  has_many :matches, through: :forecasts
end

class Championship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :season
  has_many :player_seasons
  has_many :users, through: :player_seasons
end

@playerseasons = PlayerSeason.all
```

I am iterating on: @playerseasons
I would like to compare all the PlayerSeason (@playerseasons) as following :

```
@playerseasons.each do |playerseason|
if playerseason.championship_id == @playerseason.championship
else
end
end
```

The idea is comparing all the playerseasons, if a playerseason has the same championship as the current_user, something will appears otherwise something else (basic condition).

But I'm stuck and can't access the exact championship of the current user, on the other side I can access the championship of the playerseasons.

Thank you by advance :)

Comment: Why can't you access player.champsionship? That should be loaded by devise as `current_user`.

Comment: Hello Mark, when I'm iterating on `@playerseasons` I can access `playerseason.championship`. But when I try it with `@playerseason.championship`, it appears undefined method "championship"

Comment: Why not just compare `@playerseason.championship_id` with `playerseason.championship_id`?

Comment: Yes it's exactly what I'm doing but when I'm doing `@playerseason.championship_id` it raises me an undefined method error : "undefined method `championship_id' for #<PlayerSeason::ActiveRecord_Relation:..."

Comment: How did you set the `@playerseason`? You dd not post it in the question

Comment: Hello, like this `@playerseason = PlayerSeason.where(user_id: current_user.id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not look critically at database design model which potentially could be done differently. Also I'm taking this as a non-production app as you mention in your question therefore database load optimization is a second priority.

With what you have now I would do something like just to get it to work

```
user_championships = current_user.player_seasons.map(&:championship).uniq

@playerseasons.each do |playerseason|
   if user_championships.include?(playerseason.championship)
    
    else
   end
end
```

Comment: Hello @serengeti12, indeed it works like that thank you, but I'm curious to know why the DB is not optimized ? And if this answer could handle a lot of different championships ?

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. Calling `PlayerSeason.all` for example will not scale. When you have 10 seasons and 10 users calling the code .. you'll be having (100 * associated championships) objects loaded. With either more season or users that will grow pretty quickly. You want to have a setup that loads/produces the same number of queries to DB regardless of how the database grows.

Comment: Ok I see I narrowed the scope by calling only the relevant season. Thanks a lot for your optimization insight. Thanks a lot